# Zend_Layout + helperClass

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-layout

I am try to use helperClass in Zend_Layout options.
I create a class:

```
class Helper_Testi extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract{

    public function init(){
        echo "111111111";
        $this->fff = 'hello from Helper';
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        echo "==============";
        return "message";
    }
}
```

and in Bootstrap.php try add it to Zend_Layout:

```
$options = array('layout' => 'layout','helperClass'=>'../application/controllers/helper/Testi');
$layout = new Zend_Layout();
$layout->startMvc($options);
```

But when I reload browser I see Exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "../application/controllers/helper/Testi.php" does not exist or class "../application/controllers/helper/Testi" was not found in the file'
```

What I do wrong? Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need place your helper class in correct place.

E.g. in my bootsrap there are such lines:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers() {
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();

    $view->addHelperPath('Icc/View/Helper' , 'Icc_View_Helper');
}
```

And helper files will be located in this folder: `Icc\View\Helper\`

---

Edit:

E.g. I have file `FormDropdown.php`
with such content:

```
class Icc_View_Helper_FormDropdown extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    function formDropdown($name = '')
    {
       return "<select name='$name' id='$name'></select>";
    }
}
```

In view I can use this helper in this way:

```
    <?=$this->formDropdown('icc_info_salutation')?>
```

Comment: My helper class located in application/controllers/helper/. File name Testi.php, classname Helper_Testi. I need to add helper class to layout. For example helper generate data which changed after reloading page (for example time).

Comment: My helper classes are located in `library/Icc/View/Helper` and these helpers can be used in layouts too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use APPLICATION_PATH constant in your path

Comment: It dowsn't help me. Error is the same.

Comment: ok, describe functionality of helper please, I will prompt alternative solution :)